# format amount as $xxx,xx in oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am working in Oracle Apex CMS. I need to display cost in format of $xxx,xx format.
There is format mask option in interface `FML999G999G999G999G990D00` but even after applying mask, I am not seeing cost in format.

field has pl/sql express as source which is `(nvl(:P18_COST_JOB_PROFIT,0)/100)*nvl(:P18_SUBTOTAL_LABEL_TOTAL,0)`

Answer (score 3):

1. If the field is not showing the currency symbol or decimal separator you expect:

The characters used for the `L` (currency) and `D` (decimal separator) are determined by the session `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` and `NLS_CURRENCY` settings, which by default are determined by the **Application Primary Language** (refer to **Application Attributes** -> **Globalization**).

To override the defaults provided by the Application Primary Language, you can set the session parameter in the Session Initialization PL/SQL setting (**Application Attributes** -> **Security** -> **Initialization PL/SQL Code**):

```
dbms_session.set_nls('nls_numeric_characters', q'[', ']');
dbms_session.set_nls('nls_currency', q'['$']');
```

In the example above, the decimal separator is a comma (`,`), the group separator is a space (), and the currency symbol is a `$`.

2. If the field is not using your format mask at all:

You may need to specify your format mask in the **PL/SQL Expression** directly, e.g.

```
to_char(
  nvl(:P18_COST_JOB_PROFIT,0)/100*nvl(:P18_SUBTOTAL_LABEL_TOTAL,0)
  ,'FML999G999G999G999G990D00'
  ,q'[nls_numeric_characters=', ' nls_currency='$']')
```